# how to check type first letter from enter word

Tags: jquery, text, input

I create one input text and I check first letter from enter any word that if this word was english direction to be ltr or if this word was arabic direction to be rtl.

I dont know how understand unicode first letter . please guide me .
this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.inputtext').keyup(function(){
                var text = $(this).val();
                firstLetter = text.substr(0,1);
                console.log(firstLetter);
                if(//to be english )
                {
                    console.log('english');
                }
                if(//to be arabic)
                {
                    console.log('arabic');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446244/how-to-check-if-any-arabic-character-exists-in-the-string-javascript I guess it may come in handy in your situation

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.inputtext').keyup(function(){
                var text = $(this).val();
                firstLetter = text.substr(0,1);
                console.log(firstLetter);

                var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;

                if(arabic.test(firstLetter))
                {
                    console.log('arabic');
                }
                else
                {
                   console.log('english');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QMNpS/