# Javascript - Detect Arabic Text

Tags: javascript, arabic

Today I want to make an Arabic quiz which it uses input text. Here is my code:

I know it's still basic. But the problem is it can't detect arabic text/language. When I try to input هاي text, it showed "Wrong!" alert. I don't know why it can't detect arabic language. Any solution?

```js
function answer(ans) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    if (ans.value == "هاي") {
      alert("Right!");
    } else {
      alert("Wrong!");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="answer" style="direction:RTL;"  
onkeydown="answer(this)">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters

Comment: Works normal for me: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devxlt/a2h6e7d8/). What browser are You using?

Comment: I use chrome. I'll learn informaton from @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Works in Chrome in the edited snippet

Comment: I copied the Arabic text from the second line got wrong, but if I copy this in the code, got right. I think they might be different texts?

Comment: it is showing me "right" I typed it in without copying and it is working on chorme adn IE11 but not on Firefox

Comment: what you expect as result? typing "هاي" will give you "right"

Comment: u can check this solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446244/how-to-check-if-any-arabic-character-exists-in-the-string-javascript/4446309