# How to detect if string contains Amharic language in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, unicode-string

I need to check if a string contains Amharic language, it can contain English characters as well:

```
const amharic = "የሙከራ test ሕብረቁምፊ";
amharc.match(pattern)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if any Arabic character exists in the string ( javascript )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446244/how-to-check-if-any-arabic-character-exists-in-the-string-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Using `UTF-16` range and the `charCodeAt()` method:

The `UTF-16` range for the amharic letters are from **4608** to **5017** and from **11648** to **11743** so you can use the [charCodeAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) method to check if the string characters fall within those two ranges or not.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I described above:

```js
var string = "የሙከራ test ሕብረቁምፊ";

function checkAmharic(x) {
    let flag = false;   
    [...x].forEach((e, i) => {
     if (((e.charCodeAt(i) > 4607) && (e.charCodeAt(i) < 5018)) || ((e.charCodeAt(i) > 11647) && (e.charCodeAt(i) < 11743))) {
       if (flag == false) {
         flag = true;
        }
      }
    })
    return flag; 
}

console.log(checkAmharic(string)); // will return true
console.log(checkAmharic("Hello All!!")); // will return false
```

---

### Using `ASCII` range and regex:

The `ASCII` range for the amharic letters are from `1200` to `137F` so you can use regex to check if the string characters fall within those two ranges or not.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I described above:

```js
var string = "የሙከራ test ሕብረቁምፊ";

function checkAmharic(x) {
    return /[\u1200-\u137F]/.test(x); // will return true if an amharic letter is present
}

console.log(checkAmharic(string)); // will return true
console.log(checkAmharic("A")); // will return false
```

Comment: Does the test return TRUE if an ascii 'A' is found ?

Comment: @sln No, it returns false. I have updated the answer to include testing a string which has "A" to show this. I have also added an alternative JavaScript approach that uses `UTF-16` instead to check the string for `amharic` letters. Cheers.