# Detect if ALL characters are arabic in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446244/how-to-check-if-any-arabic-character-exists-in-the-string-javascript) asks how to match if any characters in a string are arabic; fair enough, the solution works. I want to know how I can figure out if ALL characters in a string (minus whitespace) are arabic.

The solution says

> According to Wikipedia, Arabic characters fall in the Unicode range 0600 - 06FF. So you can use a regular expression to test if the string contains any character in this range:

```
var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;
var string = 'عربية‎'; // some Arabic string from Wikipedia

alert(arabic.test(string)); // displays true
```

How can I get `var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;` to match all characters and not just check for one character?

I am looking for a regex statement that I could use to match against a string, and its return value would indicate whether or not *all* the characters in a string are arabic characters.

`var arabic = /[\u0600-\u06FF]/;` <-- This is a regex statement when, when matched against a string, will indicate if *any* (one or more) of the characters in said evaluated string have arabic.

The solution I came up with is, `^[\u0600-\u06FF]{1,}$`. I don't know if this is best, I'm not regex savvy, hopefully someone who needs it can see it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match exact string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298566/match-exact-string)

Comment: Replace all the (`\s+`) with an empty string then you have to check if the entire string matches a pattern.

Comment: @Countour-Integral No, I tried that; https://regex101.com/r/N8w2TB/1. It will reject arabic strings with mroe than one character

Comment: `var arabic = /^[\u0600-\u06FF]+$/;`  or `var arabic = /^[\u0600-\u06FF]*$/;`  are all good. See https://regex101.com/r/N8w2TB/2

Comment: @JohnLexus hope the answer below is of help to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `test()` method of the `RegExp.prototype.test()` and check for the opposite, and negate it.

#### Remember

Remember that Arabic string and Arabic text is not limited to using the Arabic Characters  `/[\u0600-\u06FF]/` because in Arabic text we also use the Latin numbers and the punctuation marks like `/ \ ) ( !` , etc.

The Arabic Unicode Block `/[\u0600-\u06FF]/` see here on [Wikipedia Arabic (Unicode block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)) does not have these punctuation marks and symbols.

So also keep in mind that the following basic Latin Unicode exist in Arabic text:

`\u0020-\u0040`

`\u005B-\u0060`

`\u007B-\u007E`

Remember, even the `space` char is stored as Latin Unicode.

Here is a short function `isItAllArabic` that returns `true` or `false`:

**If you want to figure out if ALL characters in a string (minus whitespace) are Arabic, you can modify the function like this:**

```
const isItAllArabic =s=>(!/[^\u0600-\u06FF ]/.test(s));
```

```js
//======================================================
// Test if a string has only Arabic Characters
// Latin punctuation marks and number exist in Arabic
// Strings as there mostly used due to some not existing
// in Arabic Unicode letter.
//
// Output: Return true/false
//======================================================
const isItAllArabic =s=>(!/[^\u0600-\u06FF\u0020-\u0040\u005B-\u0060\u007B-\u007E]/.test(s));

//======================================================

console.log(isItAllArabic("محسن"));              // true. All Arabic text
console.log(isItAllArabic("(محسن)"));            // true. Symbols () ignored
console.log(isItAllArabic("محسن/محمد! وعلي"));  // true. Punctuations and Symbols ignored
console.log(isItAllArabic("محسن 123"));          // true as numbers are ok
console.log(isItAllArabic("محسن mohsen"));       // false because latin chars
console.log(isItAllArabic("mohsen"));            // false
```